# Shift/Reduce conflict when I introduce an action in yacc

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, bison, yacc

I am writing a front end for my C compiler, where in I am adding Type system currently. Previously I assumed everything was an int and hence the following rule worked fine.

```
declaration: datatype varList ';' { gTrace<<"declaration ";}

varList: IDENTIFIER { builder.addSymbol($1); }
    | varList',' IDENTIFIER { builder.addSymbol($3); }
    ;
```

But now I also add type to the symbol, and hence modified my rule like below:

```
 declaration: datatype { currentType = $1; } varList ';' { gTrace<<"declaration ";   currentType = -1; }

 varList: IDENTIFIER    { builder.addSymbol($1, getType(currentType)); }
    | varList',' IDENTIFIER { builder.addSymbol($3, getType(currentType)); }
    ;
```

I get a shift/reduce error when I do that, since the **{ currentType = $1; }** is being considered as an empty rule. How do I go about this error? Is there a way to specify that it is just an action?

Attached below is a snippet from my y.output

```
32 $@6: /* empty */

33 declaration: datatype $@6 varList ';'

34 varList: IDENTIFIER
35        | varList ',' IDENTIFIER
```

Comment: Hopefully useful: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bison/2001-10/msg00011.html

Comment: Thanks @sarnold, that helped. I just set my currentType value whenever i encounter a datatype token like INT, FLOAT etc.

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem? If so, please answer your question with the specifics -- I was disappointed the Lex and Yacc book didn't suggest any solutions to this problem, and that link was the closest thing I found to _useful_ -- but the questioner there relied upon the datatype to influence his _lexer_ -- I think a good solution to this problem would doubtless help others. :)

Comment: @sarnold: I have attached my solution below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem as below:

```
declaration: datatype varList ';' { gTrace<<"declaration "; currentType = -1; }

varList: IDENTIFIER { builder.addSymbol($1, getType(currentType)); }
    | varList',' IDENTIFIER { builder.addSymbol($3, getType(currentType)); }
    ;

datatype: INTEGER   { gTrace<<"int "; $$ = currentType = Type::IntegerTy; }
    | FLOAT     { gTrace<<"float "; $$ = currentType = Type::FloatTy; }
    | VOID      { gTrace<<"void "; $$ = currentType = Type::VoidTy; }
    ;
```

@sarnold, hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't get any error or warnings:

```
%token   INT
%token   FLOAT
%token   CHAR
%token   IDENTIFIER

%%

declaration: datatype { currentType = $1; } varList ';' { gTrace<<"declaration ";   currentType = -1; }

varList : IDENTIFIER                { builder.addSymbol($1, getType(currentType)); }
        | varList  ',' IDENTIFIER   { builder.addSymbol($3, getType(currentType)); }
        ;

datatype:   INT
        |   FLOAT
        |   CHAR
        ;

%%
```

Command

> % bison p.yacc
> %

I think you will need to provide more information.

The full yacc file and the parameters you are passing to yacc/bison

#### Edit

I tried your file (as per the comment) I still get no errors or warnings:

```
> yacc --version
bison (GNU Bison) 2.3
Written by Robert Corbett and Richard Stallman.

Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: The full yacc can be found at [link](https://github.com/chethanvasishta/Icarus/blob/Type/src/parser.y). I am using bison v 2.4.1. The makefile can be found at [link](https://github.com/chethanvasishta/Icarus/blob/Type/src/makefile)

Answer (score -1):

I thing you can only define an actions block for each rule, so

```
declaration: datatype { currentType = $1; } varList ';' { gTrace<<"declaration ";   currentType = -1; }
```

should be done as

```
declaration: datatype varList ';' { currentType = $1; gTrace<<"declaration ";   currentType = -1; }
```

Anyway, you are setting currentType to the lexical value of datatype and to -1 right after

Comment: No: you can do intermediate processing.